# AspectJ with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, aspectj

I've got this annotation and an aspect class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AroundHere {
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(com.annotation.AroundHere)")
    public Object redirectIfNotEditingStatus(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("hi");

        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

I want to print "hi" on some methods which has the `@AroundHere` annotation. It works fine on the service layer, but not working on the contollers. I suspect Spring Security because it scans all the controller components.

How can I make them work on the controllers?

Comment: Maybe the controllers are defined in a web context definition and your services (and your aspect) are defined in the application context?

Comment: As @micha said, most probably it's not working for you because `aop:aspectj-autoproxy` is defined in one app context and you have your controllers in a different app context. As a rule, `BeanFactoryProcessors` (which are doing the actual work when `aop:aspectj-autoproxy` is in the context) act only on the beans in the container where they are defined. So, for example, if you have `aspectj-autoproxy` defined in the root app context, it will not act on the beans defined in *-servlet.xml context.

Comment: Another reason could be that the services usually implements an interface while the controllers don't. And Spring AOP need a bean implementing an interface.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Wow, you guys were exactly correct. Please write them in an answer form so that I can give you some points. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably it's not working for you because `aop:aspectj-autoproxy` is defined in one app context and you have your controllers in a different app context. As a rule, `BeanFactoryProcessors` (which are doing the actual work when `aop:aspectj-autoproxy` is in the context) act only on the beans in the container where they are defined. So, for example, if you have `aspectj-autoproxy` defined in the root app context, it will not act on the beans defined in `*-servlet.xml` context.

You can find the relevant piece of documentation related to this subject [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-bpp):

> BeanPostProcessors are scoped per-container. This is only relevant if you are using container hierarchies. If you define a BeanPostProcessor in one container, it will only post-process the beans in that container. In other words, beans that are defined in one container are not post-processed by a BeanPostProcessor defined in another container, even if both containers are part of the same hierarchy.